# Struggling with writing beginner logical proof

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $A$ be group of groups.
Show that

$\mathscr{P}(\bigcup A)=\bigcup\{\mathscr{P}(X) \mid X \in A\}$

if and only if exist $X\in A$ so that for all $Y\in A$, $Y\subseteq X$.

Here what I did: 
$\rightarrow $
Suppose exist $X\in A$ so that for all $Y\in A$, $Y\subseteq X$.
Be $Z\in \mathscr{P}(\bigcup A)$ then $Z\subseteq\bigcup A$.

I know that I need to show that there is exist $X\in A$ so that $Z\in\mathscr{P}(X)$ so this side will be done.
However, I don't what the next step should be coming in my proof.

$\mathscr{P}$ means powerset.

Comment: "group of groups".  Do you mean "sets" or "class" or "collections".  "Group" has a specific algebraic meaning and the word should be avoided.

Comment: @fleablood Thanks, I meant sets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

($\implies$) Suppose $\mathscr{P}(\cup A) = \cup_{X \in A}\mathscr{P}(X)$. Then $\cup A \in \mathscr{P}(\cup A) \implies \cup A \in \cup_{X \in A}\mathscr{P}(X) \implies \exists X \in A: \cup A \subset X$. From this, it follows that $\forall Y \in A, Y \subset X$.

($\impliedby$) This direction is much simpler. Suppose $\exists X \in A: \forall Y \in A, Y \subset X$. Can you express $\cup A$ and $\cup_{Y \in A}\mathscr{P}(Y)$ in terms of $X$?

Comment: I have asked regarding right to left direction.. could you please give a hint what the next line in proof after Z $\subseteq$ UA?

Comment: Subsets of $\cup A$ are the union of some elements of $A$. You have assumed there is an $X$ that contains every $Y \in A$ as a subset. Can you show $Z \subset X$?

Comment: In the left to right direction we need to show that UA in A and Y in A so Y is subset of UA. Lets split it. And first lets prove UA in A. So we need to show UA = X. I have showed that UA is subset of X but can you give hint how to show that X is subset of UA. Moreover, we need to show that for all Y in A so Y is subset UA. How can we show it? Please note that I have declare X' = UA at start.